# (Exception): DateTime Magento 2.1

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework-2

Magento 2.1
При сохранении Даты (Маркетинг > Очередь рассылки > YourMailingList) вылазит ошибка:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (23 марта 2018 г. 9:34:42) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
```

Локаль ru_RU.
Как пофиксить?

Answer (score 1):

Решил так:

```
\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_time )
```

Comment: Не вижу связи между вопросом и ответов. Для вас она очевидна. А для сообщества нет. Детализируйте или вопрос или ответ. Из вашего вопроса - ответ не следует.